# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: ios

I am new in Ios programming and the below expressing is giving an error:

```
let combine = date.enumerated().map {index, date in
 return (date,self.arrFriendId[index],self.arrFriendName[index],self.arrFriendImage[index],self.arrMsgType[index],self.arrMessage[index], self.arrLastMsgTime[index], self.arrNotifyStatus[index])}
```

please help me to solve this.
thanks in advance

Comment: What is `date`? is it array of dates? Also What is the expected output that you want?

Comment: date is an array and the expected output will also be the array

Comment: This kind of large tuple is very unusual in Swift. It looks like you've created a bunch of separate arrays for each property (id, name, image), when what you really want is a `Friend` struct that has id/name/image properties. Then you'll have a single array of `Friend`, and most of these problems will go away.

Answer (score 4):

This error generally occurs when a single expression is doing a lot of things. So compiler tells you to break it to sub-expressions.

Assuming you want the output `combine` of type `Array<Any>`, You can do it like this:

```
let combine = date.enumerated().map { index, date -> Any in
    let id = self.arrFriendId[index]
    let name = self.arrFriendName[index]
    let image = self.arrFriendImage[index]
    let messageType = self.arrMsgType[index]
    let message = self.arrMessage[index]
    let messageTime = self.arrLastMsgTime[index]
    let status = self.arrNotifyStatus[index]
    return (date, id, name, image, messageType, message, messageTime, status)
}
```