# "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time" for a simple formula

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I have what appears to be a rather simple arithmetic expression:

```
       let N = 2048
//        var c = (0..<N).map{ sin( 2.0 * .pi * Float($0) / (Float(N)/2.0)) }
        let sinout = (0..<N * 10).map { x in
            sin(2 * .pi * Float(x) / Float(N / 2))
        }
```

But this is generating:

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

[image]

Why is such a simple equation not parse-able by the Swift compiler?  How do we write equations that Swift can actually parse?  This must be a major headache for persons writing `DSP` and/or linear algebra libraries: what workarounds or patterns do  you use?

Comment: ah that sounds like on to something.

Comment: @LeoDabus  Pls make that an answer.

Comment: I think it is a duplicate but I can't find

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743382/the-compiler-is-unable-to-type-check-this-expression-in-reasonable-time-try-bre

Comment: I did see that one but it is not about mathematical equations - and also the root cause and thus the answer were different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to explicitly set the return type of your map expression:

```
map { x -> Float in
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is hard for Swift to compile some seemingly easy code. The best thing you can do in those cases is modulate it in smaller chunks. I honestly think that this is an error that should be fixed but that for some reason is still there.

Comment: This is a trivial sine wave - I'm not even sure how to break it up any further.

Comment: I have tested your code and it seems not to raise any error to me, but maybe you should try something such as: let a = (0..<N * 10)
        let sinout = a.map { x in
            sin(2 * .pi * Float(x) / Float(N / 2))
        }

Comment: After adding the return code It appears to be  a case of `Command-Shift-K`

Comment: It is just a problem of cleaning the build folder?

Comment: After adding the return type which *is* needed then the issue about the `Range` was spurious : it disappeared after cleaning.  But the return type is definitely needed.